# JavaFX: Making a Tree View with Radio Buttons

Tags: treeview, javafx, radiobuttonlist

Use case: I am trying to offer a functionality where the user assembles/combines elements into a final solution. Elements would have versions. To do that, I need a combination of CheckBoxes to define which elements to include, and then Radio Buttons (nested under each check box) to define what version should be used for the selected element.

I am currently using a CheckTreeView control, from ControlsFX. but I can't find a way to put RadioButtonMenuItems as children for CheckBoxTreeItem in the tree. Is there a way to change the CheckBoxTreeItem to look like a RadioButton?

My current solution is that I am using CheckBoxItems for all tree nodes, but those that are being used for defining the version act like Radio buttons--selecting one would unselect the rest.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

EDIT: posted new question + code here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488745/javafx-radio-button-checkbox-treeview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you'll need to create your own custom TreeCellFactory that'll display a checkbox or a radiobutton as needed. Something like:

```
public class TreeCellFactory implements Callback<TreeView<Object>,TreeCell<Object>>
{
    @Override
    public TreeCell call( TreeView param )
    {
        return new TreeCell<Object>()
        {
            private final CheckBox  check = new CheckBox();
            private final RadioButton  radio = new RadioButton();
            private Property<Boolean>  prevRadioProp;
            {
                setContentDisplay( ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY );
            }

            @Override
            public void updateItem( Object item, boolean empty )
            {
                if ( prevRadioProp != null )
                {
                    radio.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional( prevRadioProp );
                    prevRadioProp = null;
                }
                check.selectedProperty().unbind();

                if ( ! empty && item != null )
                {
                    Property<Boolean> selectedProp = ....;

                    if ( getTreeItem().isLeaf() )  // display radio button
                    {
                        radio.setText( ... );
                        radio.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional( selectedProp );
                        prevRadioProp = selectedProp;
                        setGraphic( radio );
                    }
                    else                          // display checkbox
                    {
                        check.setText( ... );
                        check.selectedProperty().bind( selectedProp );
                        setGraphic( check );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    setGraphic( null );
                    setText( null );
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```