# JavaFX: Radio Button + CheckBox TreeView

Tags: treeview, radio-button, javafx-8

in reference to my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614616/javafx-making-a-tree-view-with-radio-buttons), I did the code below.

I am trying to make a treeview which shows a radio button for leafs, and checkboxes for non-leaf items. The code below does not show anything. I am sure I am doing something extremely wrong somewhere (or everywhere). Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks

```
public class RadioCheckBoxTreeView extends TreeView {

public RadioCheckBoxTreeView() {

    setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Object>, TreeCell<Object>>() {

        @Override
        public TreeCell<Object> call(TreeView<Object> param) {
            return new RadioCheckBoxCellImpl();
        }
    });
}

private static class RadioCheckBoxCellImpl extends TreeCell<Object> {

    private final CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
    private final RadioButton radio = new RadioButton();
    private Property<Boolean> prevRadioProp;

    public RadioCheckBoxCellImpl() {
    }

    {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        if (prevRadioProp != null) {
            radio.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional(prevRadioProp);
            prevRadioProp = null;
        }
        check.selectedProperty().unbind();

        if (!empty && item != null) {
            Property<Boolean> selectedProp = prevRadioProp;

            if (getTreeItem().isLeaf()) // display radio button
            {
                radio.setText("radio");
                radio.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(selectedProp);
                prevRadioProp = selectedProp;
                setGraphic(radio);
            } else // display checkbox
            {
                check.setText("check");
                check.selectedProperty().bind(selectedProp);
                setGraphic(check);
            }
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        }
    }

   }
```

this is what my start method looks like

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


    AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

    MyTreeView tv = new MyTreeView();
    tv.setRoot(new TreeItem());

    TreeItem child1 = new TreeItem();
    child1.setValue("1");

    TreeItem child2 = new TreeItem();
    child2.setValue("2");
    TreeItem child3 = new TreeItem();
    child3.setValue("3");

    tv.getRoot().getChildren().add(child1);
    tv.getRoot().getChildren().add(child2);
    child2.getChildren().add(child3);

    pane.getChildren().add(tv);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it solves the problem, but you always need `super.updateItem(item, empty);` in your `updateItem(...)` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to get this far. I also changed the graphic to change based on its type.

```
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            if (prevRadioProp != null) {
                radio.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional(prevRadioProp);
                prevRadioProp.setValue(true);
            }
            check.selectedProperty().unbind();
            if (!empty && item != null) {
                SimpleBooleanProperty selectedProp = prevRadioProp;
                if (item.getClass().getName().contains("Option")) // display radio button
                {
                    radio.setText("Option");
                    radio.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(selectedProp);
                    prevRadioProp = selectedProp;
                    setGraphic(radio);
                } else // display checkbox
                {
                    check.setText("Feature");
                    check.selectedProperty().bind(selectedProp);
                    setGraphic(check);
                }
            } else {
                setGraphic(null);
                setText(null);
            }

            super.updateItem(item, empty);
        }
```

[image]

How do I set the selection logic? Based on the code it gives a "CheckBox.selected : A bound value cannot be set." error.