# JavaFX TreeView with RadioButtons displaying incorrect status when scrolling

Tags: javafx, radio-button, treeview

I needed a `TreeView` in which some elements have `RadioButton`s.
So I had a look around, used some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614616/javafx-making-a-tree-view-with-radio-buttons) and put some of my own ideas in there.

So the result is a class (`RadioTreeView`) that extends `TreeView` with custom `TreeItem`s and `TreeCell`s.

Everything works fine, apart from one, important thing:

**When scrolling through the `TreeView` with one `RadioButton` selected, other buttons will appear to be selected.**
This gif demonstrates the problem.(I'm not clicking anywhere while scrolling)

[image: Short Video]

Through some debugging, I found out that the *selectedItem*-Property of the `ToggleGroup` (which is shared by all of the `RadioButton`s in the `TreeView`), actually never changes.
And when I added a listener to each of the `RadioButton`s' *selected*-Property, they never fired either.

So that leaves me puzzled and wondering, if it's a JavaFX bug or if I'm missing something very obvious.

**Here's my code:**

```
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class RadioTreeView<T> extends TreeView<T> {
    private ToggleGroup toggleGroup; // shared by all radioButtons

    public RadioTreeView() {
        super();
        toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<T>, TreeCell<T>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<T> call(TreeView<T> param) {
                return new RadioTreeCell<T>(toggleGroup);
            }
        });

    }

    public static class RadioTreeItem<T> extends TreeItem<T> {
        private final boolean hasRadio; // defines whether a RadioButton should be shown

        public RadioTreeItem(boolean hasRadio, T item) {
            super(item);
            this.hasRadio = hasRadio;
        }

        public boolean getHasRadio() {
            return hasRadio;
        }
    }

    public static class RadioTreeCell<T> extends TreeCell<T> {
        private final RadioTreeButton<T> radio = new RadioTreeButton<T>();
        private final ToggleGroup toggleGroup;

        public RadioTreeCell(ToggleGroup toggleGroup) {
            super();
            this.toggleGroup = toggleGroup;
        }

        {
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (!empty && item != null) {
                setText(item.toString());
                if (((RadioTreeItem<T>) getTreeItem()).getHasRadio()) { // display radioButton as graphic
                    setGraphic(radio);
                    radio.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            } else {
                setGraphic(null);
                setText(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class RadioTreeButton<T> extends RadioButton {
        // non-important methods removed

        public RadioTreeButton() {
        }
    }
```

Any help is hugely appreciated.

**PS: I know my code isn't perfect**

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is the behaviour that only a single `RadioButton` can be selected in the entire `TreeView` desired or not?

Comment: @fabian yes, it is. That is why they share one ToggleGroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeCell`s are reused. This means a single `RadioButton` may be used in a cell containing different `TreeItem`s. You never update the selection state of a `RadioButton` in a cell based on the item. This results in the same `RadioButton` remaining selected. When you scroll, different `TreeItem`s are put into different cells. The text of the `TableCell`s is updated, but the selection state of their `RadioButton` is not.

You need to store the selected `TreeItem` somehow, e.g. using the `userData` property of the `ToggleGroup`:

```
public RadioTreeCell(ToggleGroup toggleGroup) {
    this.toggleGroup = toggleGroup;
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT); // initializer code moved to constructor

    // update userData for toggleGroup, when new radio becomes selected
    radio.selectedProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            toggleGroup.setUserData(getTreeItem());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (!empty && item != null) {
        setText(item.toString());
        RadioTreeItem<T> treeItem = (RadioTreeItem<T>) getTreeItem();
        if (treeItem.getHasRadio()) { // display radioButton as graphic
            setGraphic(radio);
            radio.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

            // update selection based on toggleGroup userData
            radio.setSelected(toggleGroup.getUserData() == treeItem);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    } else {
        setGraphic(null);
        setText(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it makes sense. I wasn't aware that `TreeCell`s are being reused.
Thanks a lot for the effort.